# Will gate agents in London know if I'm "undesirable" before my stop-over in Johannesburg?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, south-africa, jnb

I was recently deemed "undesirable" in South Africa for overstaying my visa. I want to visit my South African fiance in Botswana but all of the affordable flights stop at OR Tambo. Will the gate agents for my connecting flight before SA know I am not allowed in the country and prevent me from boarding? I don't want to get stopped in London/Zurich and not have Christmas with my fiance.

Comment: I did not feel like the responses to that question had any stolid evidence behind it. I'm hoping to find out if the gate agents at my layover before Johannesburg will stop me before going to SA

Answer (score 1):

> Also will the gate agents in my connecting flight before SA know I am not allowed in the country and prevent me from boarding?

No they will not, as South Africa doesn't do advance passenger screening.

Unlike most countries, South Africa *does* perform "border" control for transit passengers, but as you're not trying to entering the country, not much if anything will happen.

So you should definitely be fine.

Comment: I believe South Africa does do check-in screening. South Africa implemented an Advance Passenger Information system for the 2010 World Cup. https://www.sita.aero/resources/type/customers-stories/south-africa-border-security He might therefore be refused boarding.

Comment: @RodneyHawkins I called South African airways, and they said SA doesn't do it